# Why isn't there any tool for making quick scores on this SE?

Tags: feature-request

Math stack exchange implements Latex language to quickly draw math. It should be useful to implements a similar tool for scores in order to develop or criticized one's interprtation of the chords of a song.

So why isn't there any tool for making quick scores on this SE?

Comment: We've been trying to get lilypond implemented on the site for a while now http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/913/7222

Comment: okay, I didn't knew It even existed, thanks, I hope it would be implemented soon!